# Android-Output of an ArrayList not displayed

Tags: android, arraylist

I have written a code to get the contents of an arrayList but instead of that i am getting random numbers as output.

Student.java

```
    package com.example.com.arraylist;

    public class Student {

        int Enrno;
        String Name;

       public Student(int Enrno, String Name){

           this.Enrno=Enrno;
           this.Name=Name;
        }
    }
```

MainActivity.java

```
    package com.example.com.arraylist;
    import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.widget.Toast;

    import java.util.ArrayList;

    public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

        @Override
       protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
           setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    Student s1=new Student(1,"Rahul");
    Student s2=new Student(2,"Rajiv");
    Student s3=new Student(3,"Rohan");

    ArrayList<Student> studentArrayList=new ArrayList<Student>();

    studentArrayList.add(s1);
    studentArrayList.add(s2);
    studentArrayList.add(s3);

    for(Student a:studentArrayList)
        System.out.println(a);

       }
   }
```

Output:

```
   I/System.out: com.example.com.arraylist.Student@d6765f3
                 com.example.com.arraylist.Student@308a2b0
                 com.example.com.arraylist.Student@5f1529
```

i want to display content using this for-loop itself.
Thanks.

Comment: You are printing object student, so its printing hashtag. You should print object content.

Comment: for(Student a:studentArrayList)
        System.out.println(a.Enrno + " " + a.Name);

       }

Comment: It's not a random numbers, but default `Object.toString()` output. This method concats class name and instance hashcode by default.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Override `toString()` in your `Student` class as follows:

```
@Override
public String toString() {
    return "Data: Name= "+this.Name+" Enrno= "+this.Enrno;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `getter` and `setter` method to retrieve data from your `Student` class

create `getter` and `setter` method in your `Student` class like below code

Try this

```
public class Student {

    int Enrno;
    String Name;

    public Student(int Enrno, String Name){

        this.Enrno=Enrno;
        this.Name=Name;
    }

    public int getEnrno() {
        return Enrno;
    }

    public void setEnrno(int enrno) {
        Enrno = enrno;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return Name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        Name = name;
    }
}
```

**activity code**

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        Student s1 = new Student(1, "Rahul");
        Student s2 = new Student(2, "Rajiv");
        Student s3 = new Student(3, "Rohan");

        ArrayList<Student> studentArrayList = new ArrayList<Student>();

        studentArrayList.add(s1);
        studentArrayList.add(s2);
        studentArrayList.add(s3);

        for (Student a : studentArrayList) {

            System.out.println(a.getEnrno());
            System.out.println(a.getName());


        }


    }

}
```